# Img does not load in Knitr output from .Rmd to .md for Jekyll/GitHub site

Tags: r, r-markdown, jekyll, knitr, github-flavored-markdown

I run a GitHub pages Jekyll site with the [minimal mistakes theme](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) and have spent all day yesterday trying to knit a `.Rmd` to `.md` with the proper formatting and relative file paths. I ran into a [file pathing issue which is perfectly described here](http://www.randigriffin.com/2017/04/25/how-to-knit-for-mysite.html). I tried her workaround and it works as described.

This is where my site lives locally:

- Root: `~/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/`

  - Root directory is also an `.Rproj`
- `.Rmd` files: `~/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/_reports/`
- `ggplot2` output from .Rmd: `~/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/_reports/figure/`

Below you will find my repex `.Rmd` where I'm trying to include both an image and an output from `ggplot2` in the resulting `.md` file.

```r
---
title: "repex"
author: "Max Kruisbrink"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  md_document:
    variant: gfm
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())

# define knitr paths
base.dir <- "~/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/"
base.url <- "/"
fig.path <- "_reports/figure/"

# set knitr parameters
opts_knit$set(base.dir = base.dir, base.url = base.url)
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = fig.path)
```

```r
{r tidyverse}

knitr::include_graphics("img/icons/r-packages/thumbs/tidyverse.png")
```

```r
{r ggplot-examples}

# loads ggplot 
library(tidyverse) 

# using the starwars dataset
data <- starwars

# plot the height distribution
ggplot(data, aes(height)) + 
         geom_density(aes(color = sex))
```

And these are the two links included in the resulting `.md` file

```r
![](/img/icons/r-packages/thumbs/tidyverse.png)

![](/_reports/figure/ggplot-examples-1.png)
```

As you can see, the relative file paths are correct when considering Jekyll requires relative file paths from the root directory.

But... for some reason ONLY the `tidyverse.png` image is loaded correctly when I build my site locally. I receive this error when I load the page on localhost with the relative links:

`[2022-08-12 16:06:08] ERROR "/_reports/figure/ggplot-examples-1.png" not found.`

When I use the full path `![](D:/Username/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/_reports/figure/ggplot-examples-1.png)` I don't get the error but there's no image either.

When I inspect the local page in devtools next to VSC I fail to see where the error is. The link appears correct to me?

[image: VSC + Devtools + Localhost Screenshot]

The file is there! I'm at a loss. Anyone able to shine light on my case? I'm much obliged.

**Live edits**

- When I try to PreviewHTML my knitted repex `.md` file locally with relative file paths, it loads no images at all. When I add the full paths both images are loaded.
- When I push repex to GH, the image loads in the repo itself
- When I visit the live blogpost, it is not loading again.

Anyone any ideas? Halp

Comment: This may be a dumb question... did you try running `include_graphics()` for both images? This embeds the image. Another idea: did you use the Application pane in Jekyll to see what you imported as that image? (If you're not aware, bottom left, under *Frames*.)

Comment: Yes I tried this in a new code block with a relative path from root. Same result with same link structure... I don't see what you mean with the Application pane 'in Jekyll' as I'm building from VSC. Could you include a screenshot?

Comment: For the Application pane, I meant in developer tools—in the browser. I do have another question; what's the light bulb in VSC telling you? Separately—have you tried previewing the page in VSC before rendering it in the browser?

Comment: The application pane shows me the correct relative path to the image itself. The light bulb just mentions surround options for wrappers and headings. I'm so clueless right now.

Comment: You should see the actual image in the Application pane. Take a look at either the application pane or the source pane. If you can't find it in either, your webpage can't `see`  the folder you've stored the image in. Another thing you might look at is the head of the webpage. You should see those images in the head--likely encoded in base64. When I ran some images with your YAML, the images were in `style` tags.

Comment: I ran another test and changed the folder name from `_reports/figure/` to `img/rmd/` and it worked. I'm pretty sure I tried that at the start but I must have missed something. I'm guessing it is a YAML/Jekyll thing where the _ in front of a folder name messes things up? I was sure it must be something simple like this from the start... Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, the whole `_reports/figure/` folder wasn't recognized properly. When I changed the relative path for the `.Rmd` report figures to `img/rmd/` using the same method, the images loaded correctly.